# How do I set up a function that returns a pointer to a vector in C++?

Tags: function, visual-c++, pointers

I need help figuring out bits of code. I need a function that loads up a vector with given strings and returns a pointer. I plan to use it to generate multiple vectors and then use the pointer to display them.

I am not sure how to set up both the return of the pointer by the function and the later display of the vectors. Please make suggestions only on lines that contain //HELP NEEDED HERE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int pointerReturner (string str1, string str2) //HELP NEEDED HERE
{
    vector<string> vList;
    vList.push_back(str1); 
    vList.push_back(str2); 
    return vList; //HELP NEEDED HERE
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    vector<string> vMakeList1;
    vMakeList1 =pointerReturner("Honda","Toyota");//HELP NEEDED HERE
    for (vector<string>::iterator n=vMakeList1.begin(); n!=vMakeList1.end();++n)
    {
        cout<<*n<<endl;
    }

    vector<string> vMakeList2;
    vMakeList2=pointerReturner("Chrysler","Ford");//HELP NEEDED HERE
    for (vector<string>::iterator n=vMakeList2.begin(); n!=vMakeList2.end();++n)
    {
        cout<<*n<<endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate the vector dynamically using the new operator. Otherwise the vector is just an automatic variable that is destroyed after the function pointerReturner ends. You also have to change the return type of this function from int to a pointer to a vector (vector*). 
But if you allocate an object dynamically you have to destroy it explicitly using the delete operator, otherwise the allocated memory will never be released which would result in a memory leak.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string>* pointerReturner (string str1, string str2)
{
    vector<string> *vList = new vector<string>();
    vList->push_back(str1); 
    vList->push_back(str2); 
    return vList;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    vector<string> *vMakeList1;
    vMakeList1 = pointerReturner("Honda","Toyota");
    for (vector<string>::iterator n=vMakeList1->begin(); n!=vMakeList1->end();++n)
    {
        cout<<*n<<endl;
    }
    delete vMakeList1;

    vector<string> *vMakeList2;
    vMakeList2=pointerReturner("Chrysler","Ford");
    for (vector<string>::iterator n=vMakeList2->begin(); n!=vMakeList2->end();++n)
    {
        cout<<*n<<endl;
    }
    delete vMakeList2;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See also my edit, you have to remeber to delete the allocated vector once it is no longer needed.

Comment: can you edit, replace <delete vmakeList1> with <delete vMakeList1> and <delete vmakeList2> with <delete vMakeList2>, for posterity?

Comment: sure :) now it should compile

Comment: does it matter when I delete the allocated vector?

Comment: you can delete it whenever you want, however after you delete it, you can't use it anymore (if you try segmentation fault will happen certainly). When you delete an object you get back the memory it used. If you don't delete the object and the pointer to it is lost (like when you overwrite it with some other value) then this memory will never be reclaimed until the program is finished. For the two simple vectors it doesn't seem to be much, but that's the rule to always remember to delete objects, otherwise the memory usage of your program will grow indefinitely until it crashes.

Comment: consider a loop: `for (int i=0; i<1000000;++i) vMakeList1 = pointerReturner("Honda","Toyota");` this will cause 1000000 vectors to be created and never destroyed, if your program would continue after it, then this memory would still be reserved